# How to use a deployment variable from bitbucket in a JavaScript file which return a custom config vars based on env variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm developing a react application which is deployed using the bitbucket pipeline. I have created custom deployment environments and custom pipeline settings to deploy the app into multiple domains with different configurations. Also, defined the env variables in the `.env` file and `webpack.config.js` file.

And the application is running seamlessly in the local. But when I deploy it using bitbucket the variable(`REACT_APP_APP_NAME`) is coming as `undefined`. In most of the posts/questions, I have seen that people were told to push that into the repository variable.

However, I have configured all the .env variables in the deployment variables since each deployment takes the same key but different values.

Below is the JS file(`config.js`) which used the `.env` variable.

```
export const SITES = {
  app_1: {
    name: "First app",
  },
  app_2: {
    name: "Second app",
  }
}

export const APP = SITES[REACT_APP_APP_NAME]['name']
```

And the REACT_APP_APP_NAME is defined in `.env, webpack.config.js` for local and in `deployment variables` for CI/CD.

Eg:- In web pack.
REACT_APP_APP_NAME: JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_APP_NAME),

And here is the pipeline file.

```
image: node:10.15.3

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &test
        name: Run test suite
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm test
    - step: &deploy
        size: 2x
        artifacts:
          - dist/**
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=7128
          - npm install
          - npm run build
          - ***other steps which take care of deployment

pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *test
  branches:
    develop:
      - step: *test
      - step:
          <<: *deploy
          name: Deploy to app1
          deployment: app1deployment
      - step:
          <<: *deploy
          name: Deploy to app 2 
          deployment: app2deployment
          trigger: manual
```

When the `npm test` runs, the `REACT_APP_APP_NAME` is coming as undefined.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.
export const APP_NAME = SITE_CONFIG[REACT_APP_APP_NAME]["name"];
```